# using remote attribute for model validation in asp.net core 2.0 api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-2.0

I am creating a rest api and want to validate my model. I am using remote attribute for one of my fields as it need to check records from database. But the controller with remote field property never gets called. below is the code.

**Model.**

```
 public class APIBusinessDetailModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Industry is required")]
        [Remote("CheckRecordExists", "RegistrationAPIController")]
        public string Industry { get; set; }
        public string RegisteredBusinessType { get; set; }
        public string ABN { get; set; }
        public string BusinessBriefDescription { get; set; }
        public string BusinessStreet { get; set; }
        public string BusinessCity { get; set; }
        public string BusinessState { get; set; }
        public string BusinessPostcode { get; set; }
        public string BusinessWebsite { get; set; }
    }
```

**controller Action**

```
  public async Task<JsonResult> CheckRecordExists(string Industry)
    {
        return Json("Not a valid Industry in Business Model");
    }
```

Comment: I second this question, even my API is not using the remote validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the controller name parameter to "RegistrationAPI".

Also check that your HttpMethod on the Remote attribute matches with what the remove validation method will accept.